# Format datetime to HH:MM, AM/PM

Tags: go, time, datetime-format

If I have a string in datetime in this format `2020-11-03T06:30:00.000Z`

how to get only `HH:MM AM/PM` out of it like `06:30 AM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse ***string*** value use `time.Parse(layout, value string)` and then `parsed.Format(layout string)` the ***result*** (look at [src/time/format.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go), [src/time/format_test.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format_test.go))

```
date := "2020-11-03T06:30:00.000Z"
parsed, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date)
fmt.Println(parsed)
fmt.Println(parsed.Format("15:04 PM"))
```

0utput

```
2020-11-03 06:30:00 +0000 UTC
06:30 AM
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/o559CeciqTk)</kbd>